# order by nulls first in descending order in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, sql-order-by, sql-null

I want to sort the values of the table in descending order and the null value is in the first, like this:

```
null
null
2020-09-27 16:36:17 
2020-09-27 18:20:30
2020-09-27 22:45:26
2020-09-28 02:11:14
2020-09-28 10:31:43
```

I used the following code but it did not work

```
Source::orderBy('last_rank_update', 'asc')->get();
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ascending sort, `null` values appear last by default (and first in a descending sort). Postgres provide a way to override the default sort ordering `null` with option `nulls first` and `nulls last`.

You could use it with `orderByRaw`:

```
Source::orderByRaw('last_rank_update nulls first')
```